# material ui select - add horizontal scroll to dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, material-ui

In my project I am using material ui Select component and the problem is that dropdown contents is very long and does not fit in.

[image: Pic]

For these purposes I need to add a horizontal scroll to dropdown menu. I tried adding property OverflowX to menuProps and to sx props but it did not work. Any ideas how to fix the issue?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/selectautowidth-demo-material-ui-forked-x46z1z?file=/demo.js:641-650)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added a codesandbox link. You can check the solution here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/selectautowidth-demo-material-ui-forked-8yl3n9?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this part of the code.

```
const MenuProps = {
autoFocus: false,
//OverflowX: "scroll",
PaperProps: {
  style: {
    //maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
    width: 250,
    OverflowX: "scroll"
  }
}
};
```

`width` and `overflowX`, so you were really close the styling is correct just fix width and overflow.

```
const MenuProps = {
autoFocus: false,
//OverflowX: "scroll",
PaperProps: {
  style: {
    //maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
    width: "250px",
    overflowX: "scroll"
  }
}
```

};